# Please add a tag for Google BigQuery

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tagging

Please add a `google-bigquery` tag (see [tag info on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-bigquery/info)). DBA.SE questions that would be covered by this tag include:

- [Aggregating two queries and returning a COUNT of some permutations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89194/41669)
- [Alternatives for storing 365TB of info](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/89847/41669)
- [Counting unique records across 2 columns and computing a score based on boolean values](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/95773/41669)
- [BigQuery daily cron jobs](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/141259/41669)
- [How do I improve my data analyst team's review process for queries?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/146547/41669)

Some questions related to BigQuery are currently using the `bigtable` tag, even though these are completely different databases, because that's the closest one available.

Comment: Why is the tag `google-bigquery` and not just `bigquery`? We don't have `miscrosost-sql-server`, `ibm-db2`, `oracle-mysql`, `oracle-oracle` ...

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ – FWIW, it's already `google-bigquery` on SO, and for the tag `bigtable` on SO, it's frequently misused to mean simply "a large table", in questions completely unrelated to Bigtable, but about an entirely separate SQL db.

Comment: yeah, I can understand how that can happen. It also happens frequently for other general tags (e.g "sql" that is misused, instead of "query" or "sql-server"). I can see how "big-query" will have similar effect. Still it doesn't feel very right, either here or at SO.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok. I have added this tag with the SO description as a starting point and added it to the linked questions.